# Gtk conversation effect

Tags: c++, c, gtk, ubuntu-10.04

I was using some gnome applications like empathy and gwibber, and was wondering how to create a "conversation" effect in my own gtk application.

E.g. http://www.ubuntu.com.cn/files/1004features/01.jpg (off google, not my site)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think these are actually done with HTML and WebKitGtk. Of course, you can always look at the empathy and gwibber source code: http://git.gnome.org/browse/empathy and http://gwibber.com